# How to apply styles for v-slot?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
<template>
<div>
 <app-tabs  class="w-11/12 lg:w-10/12 mx-auto" :tabList="contentList"  variant="horizontal">
 <template  v-for="content in contentList" v-slot:[content.SID]="">
 <div class="align-items">{{ content.id }}<br/> //not breaking line and giving error
 {{ content.name }}{{ content.val}}</div>
 </template>
</app-tabs>
</div>
</template>
```

Unable to add **css  class** inside of vuejs slots. I am getting error as,

error  Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives  vue/require-v-for-key

Is there any way to add css class, or any other alternative ways to do it?
With internet resources, I found the way to do it by **Deep Selectors** like >>> but not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error occurs because the key (`:key="uniqueID"`) is missing. Add in your loop a key like :

```
<template  v-for="content in contentList" v-slot:[content.SID]="">
   <div :key="content.id" class="align-items">{{ content.id }}<br/> 
 {{ content.name }} {{ content.val }}</div>
</template>
```